# Methods for generic class of only a specific type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a Vector class defined like this:

```
class Vector<N extends number> {...}
```

where N is the size (or dimension) of the vector.
The vector has a cross product method, that calculates the cross product:

```
cross(vector: Vector<N>) {...}
```

The problem is, that the cross product is only defined for 3 dimensions (N extends 3). So my question is: Is there any way to "hide" the cross product method from all vectors except for 3-dimensional ones? I don't want to use a subclass like 3DVector, that implements the cross product method. The best solution I could think of is the following:

```
cross(vector: N extends 3 ? Vector<3> : never) {...}
```

But this doesn't hide the method, it just kind of "disables" it, by setting the parameter to never. Is there any solution to my problem or anything thats better than my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subclass of `Vector`, something like `Vector3D` that would define the `cross` method. This allowes you to "hide" the method to the other vector.

```
export class Vector<N extends number> {
    /* ... */
}

export class Vector3D extends Vector<3> {
    cross(vector: Vector3D) {
        /* ... */
    }
}

export class Vector2D extends Vector<2> {
    /* ... */
}

const vectorWithCross = new Vector3D();
const vectorWithoutCross = new Vector2D();
const genericVector = new Vector<390>();

vectorWithCross.cross(new Vector3D()) // works fine

vectorWithoutCross.cross(new Vector3D()) // error
genericVector.cross(new Vector3D()) // error
```

[Here is a typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DVgJtAHgDk5QZgA7AE0woFcBbAI2CgD44BvAWACg4BcAPQAqOADpJcEUL4BfPn1CRYiVBmy58UAMwARUiHLVMOPIR0ce-QQigQMACgBuW6AC5N53XoCUXPkEg4TFJcWlZGwEFXhilcGh4ZHRTNygAJgMyShovbQJ0q0DBUQkpGXlFXgQICjR4V28AdQBLGAALAGF7DQBeOApgAHc86H1HXwBuPhq6hrTWjog6GG6HTH7BkbNtTInp6tr6uABzSlYWhB3oOE3h0agCHQBOAAY2farG7UWunrRxHZ1o4tg9xr5-EIhHAhtAANaYABmLUGfG+0F+y1W-0B-xB92uPgmkOhrHsUD4Z0GUEuhNxwNBhPBJNIUHJQA) if you which to play around with that.

Comment: Thank you, but I came to the conclusion I don't want to make an entire subclass just for the one extra method. I should have said that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you were not using generics, but instead were defining classes `Vector1d`, `Vector2d`, `Vector3d`, etc. In that case, if `cross` only applies to `Vector3d`, you would not implement it in any of the others and try to 'hide' it -- e.g. if they all inherit from `Vector` you would add the method in the derived class.

Similarly, I feel that if a method only applies to a particular value of the generic, then it should probably not be a method of the generic type.

I am not familiar enough with TypeScript to provide a specific answer for that, but in general I would say that `cross` needs to be a global / free function, not a member of the class:

```
class Vector<N extends Number> { ... };

// ...

function cross(Vector<3>, Vector<3>) -> Vector<3>;
```

or you could create a separate class for 3D vectors, and implement it there:

```
class Vector<N extends Number> { ... };

// ...

class Vector3D extends Vector<3> {
  // ...
  function cross(Vector3D, Vector3D) -> Vector3D { 
   // ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had the idea of using subclasses to, but eventually I decided not to use it, because it wouldn't quite fit with the idea of the generic approach (and its a bit overkill for just one method). But as you explained, it's intended to do with subclasses, so there's probably no real way to do it like I want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but you can try this.

```
// normal vector class but without cross method
class vector<N extends number>{...}

// add the cross method to the prototype manually
vector.prototype.cross = function (other: vector<3>) {...}

// define the vector interface again with the cross method added on, typescript interfaces are extendable like this
interface vector<N extends number>{
    cross: (N extends 3 ? (other: vector<3>) => vector<3> : never)
}
```

The important part of this is the type definition of cross. It's based on the type argument. If it's 3, cross is a method, if not, cross is never. It'll still show up in autocomplete if N isn't 3 but at least it won't be callable.